# Adding point to a scatterplot on touch but it is working only for the first touch event (achartengine)

Tags: android, achartengine, touch-event

Here is my OnTouchListener()

```
private GraphicalView mChart;

mChart.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                      xy = mChart.toRealPoint(0);
                          flagtouch =1;
                          seriestouch.add(xy[0],xy[1]);
                          addseries();
                          view.removeView(mChart);
                          mChart=null;
                      drawgraph(ch); 
                }
                    return false;
            }
     });
```

addseries function is as follows:-

```
private void addseries()
{
            XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Series 1");
                for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
                {
                    series.add(value1[i],value2[i]);
                }
                dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
                dataset.addSeries(series);
                if(flagtouch==1)
                {
                dataset.addSeries(seriestouch);
                }
    }
```

and drawgraph function is as follows:-

```
    private void drawgraph()
     {       

           mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
           XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            renderer.setColor(Color.RED);
            renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
            renderer.setFillPoints(true);
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
             if(flagtouch==1)
              {
                    XYSeriesRenderer renderer1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
                    renderer1.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    renderer1.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
                    renderer1.setFillPoints(true);
                    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer1);
              }
            mRenderer.setXTitle(colnam.get(0));
            mRenderer.setYTitle(colnam.get(1));
            mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
            mRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{10,45,60,0});
            title.setText("Scatter Plot");
            mChart = ChartFactory.getScatterChartView(this, dataset, mRenderer);
            view.addView(mChart);
    }
```

The new point is shown on the graph but only for the first touch event, for subsequent touch  events touchlistener() is not called at all I checked this using Log and further if I remove the statement  " mChart = ChartFactory.getScatterChartView(this, dataset, mRenderer);" whenever flagtouch=1 then  touchlistener() is called on every touch but it is of no use as nothing changes in the graph.

Comment: what are value1[i],value2[i] ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mChart.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    double[] xy = mChart.toRealPoint(0);
                series.add(xy[0], xy[1]);
                dataset.clear();
                    dataset.addSeries(series);
                    mChart.repaint();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```